# weird bug with ranges over canvases

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input, range

This jsfiddle:[http://jsfiddle.net/SDR2W/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Anyway, the sliders have a system so the top shade will never be darker than the bottom.  But when you drag any of the ranges upward, at a value of 10, the sliders act weird, and i don't understand why. (the ranges are hidden on the side of the canvases) wondrin if any of you see the problem?

Thanks

```
   <input type="range" class="vs1 vs" min="0" max="45" style="left:-89px;top:-12px" id="vs1" />
    <input type="range" class="vs2 vs" min="0" max="45" style="right:-89px;top:-12px" id="vs2" />
    <style>
input {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:arial;
    outline:none;
}
input[type=range].vs {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: none;
    width: 200px;
    height:28px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    margin-top: 97px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    opacity:0.4;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
input[type="range"].vs1::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: black;
    width: 5px;
    height: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius:2em;
    border-top-left-radius:2em;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
}
input[type="range"].vs2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: black;
    width: 5px;
    height: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:2em;
    border-bottom-left-radius:2em;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 7px;
}
input[type=range]:hover.vs {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(100%, #ffcb93), color-stop(73%, #ffd8af), color-stop(0%, #ffffff));
    border:1px solid black;
    opacity:1;
}
input[type=range]:active.vs {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(100%, #ffcb93), color-stop(73%, #ffd8af), color-stop(0%, #ffffff));
    border:1px solid black;
    opacity:1;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about the user interaction you refer to when you say "drag any of the ranges upward"? Or what "act weird" means, so the reader could know if he guessed right? Also what is a "wondrin"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had this tagged as jQuery, so I have reduced & simplified it by somewhat actually using jQuery:

```
if (~~$('#vs1').val() > ~~$('#vs2').val()) {
    if (qwas == 1) $('#vs2').val($('#vs1').val())
    if (qwas == 2) $('#vs1').val($('#vs2').val())
}
```

### jSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ZYX8Y/3/

Note: `~~` converts a value to an integer (including strings). Much simpler & faster than parseInt()

*Another note: At first I managed to easily break your code as there are no braces on the nested ifs... really bad practice for code maintenance.*

Comment: +1 on missing braces. Also, he's not coherent on semicolons and indentation, which are all style features important for maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't compare strings directly. The `value` property gives you strings.
So `"1"` and `"10"` don't compare as you think.

To solve your problem use:

```
parseInt(obj.value, 10)
```

where `obj` is the DOM element you get with `document.getElementById()`.

Use this everywhere, in the `if()` and in the `get` and `set` of your assignments.